# website written in HTML using iWeb doesn't show up correctly in different browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, iweb

I have a question regarding how to make the same website appear consistently in different browsers on different platforms.

The following is a website that I made for my professor: http://youlab.wustl.edu/Home.html. The site itself was made using iWeb while the drop down menu was manually inserted using an external HTML code provider (SoThink DHTML).

While Firefox displays the site correctly, all the other browsers had some sort of problem displaying the site.

- Internet Explorer: none of the links work
- Chrome & Safari: the drop down menu is shifted all the way to the left, and were not clickable since it disappeared when the mouse moved towards it.

The movie on 1 page doesn't work either.

Could someone tell me what is wrong and how to fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the web world, auto generated pages are just a bad idea.

Comment: And you want to know what?  Why "Firefox displays the site correctly, all the other browsers had some sort of problem displaying the site"?  Are you asking why browsers are different?  Did you read this yet? http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the computer programming skill to do much else. I have to work with what I have.

Comment: "I have to work with what I have" In which case, you have browser compatibility problems.  What's your question, then?

Comment: Unfortunately, cross-browser web development is not easy, so your question is pretty much unanswerable here. The best I can say is iWeb is a bad development platform. Either re-create it in a platform that works for you *and* is cross-browser compliant, or hire someone to fix what iWeb made.

Comment: @ S. Lott: Thank you for the link! Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the table... Which row am I supposed to be looking at? I would like to know how to fix this problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: What platform do you recommend that I use to make the site? I don't know how to program at all...

Comment: "What platform do you recommend that I use to make the site?".  That's a separate question.  Before you ask.  Search.  Search here carefully for web development platform.  After you read **all** the answers, formulate your question carefully.  Unless we know what you're trying to accomplish, we can't help.  At all.

Comment: "What platform do you recommend..." I don't know of any platform that will let someone without programming knowledge design a custom webpage that displays correctly on every major browser.  If such a thing existed, its developers would be filthy rich and I wouldn't have a job.

Comment: All right, thanks guys! I have come to realize that this is a problem larger than that I can solve. I will turn it into a professional's hand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your answer

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser

Comment: Thanks! What platform do you recommend that I use to make the site? I don't know how to program at all...